# Obtener un resultado de una función que posee EXEC en su estructura

Tags: sql, sql-server

Deseo hacer una función en SQL Server, que me permita devolver un formato de una serie de valores que se encuentran en varios archivos. Con indicarle el nombre del archivo, y el registro, sería suficiente, y lo que he logrado hasta ahora, es programar lo siguiente:

```
create function [dbo].[Suc_Nro](@Archivo varchar(25), @Remito Int)
Returns varchar(13)
As
Begin
Declare @SucNro varchar(13);
Declare @sql varchar(600) = 'Select top(1) convert(varchar(4), 
Format(case When sucursal = 0 then 0 else Sucursal End, ''0000'')) + ''-'' + 
convert(varchar(8), Format(Nro, ''00000000'')) 
From dbo.' + @Archivo + ' Where Id = ' + 
convert(varchar(10),@remito)
Exec(@sql)
End;
```

El problema se me plantea en la devolución, ya que necesito devolver el resultado del EXEC, y no sé cómo acoplarlo a una variable de respuesta, por ejemplo, `@Respuesta = EXEC(@Sql)`
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la atención.
Ya confirmé que no se puede ejecutar un comando "Exec" dentro de una función en SQL server, por lo que me resulta imposible llamar a una transacción mediante esta orden, dentro de una función.
Para poder hacerlo, debería utilizarse un procedimiento, que no es lo más cómodo para mi necesidad.

De todos modos, gracias por el espacio, si a alguien le sirve mi experiencia, ya valió la pena el intento.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).